# Subgroup of the orthogonal group generated by reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

What is the subgroup of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ generated by relections  around  $k$-dimensional hyperplanes?

For $k=n-1$ it is $O(n)$ by the Cartan's theorem. For $k=0$ it is $\{\pm Id \}$. What about the other cases?

Edit. By a reflection $S$ on $X$ I mean a linear orthogonal mapping such that $S^2=Id$. By a reflection around $k$-dimensional hyperplane $V\subset X$ I mean the reflection for which the set of fixed points (linear subspace) $V$ has dimension $k$.

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetries wrt a k-dimensional" subspace? How can you mean this in such a way that the only symmetries of 0 are $+/- 1$?

Comment: Also in what way are you using Cartan's thm. here? And what theorem are you using?

Comment: Cartan thr. says that the orthogonal mapping in the Euclidean space is a composition of symmetries with respect to hyperplanes .

Comment: So you mean reflections around $k$-dimensional hyperplanes?

Comment: Yes, it should be reflection. I wrote ''symmetry'' because  I was not sure of   the name.